# How does bcrypt-ruby obscure the passwords of a hacked database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bcrypt, bcrypt-ruby

I am trying to understand how `has_secure_password` works. On the bcrypt-ruby [website](https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby) has the following below examples of how to use it. The `password` method of class `User` confuses me. It looks like the code `@password ||= Password.new(password_hash)` takes the encrypted hash and gives back the unencrypted password. It shouldn't be possible to recover the password from just the encrypted hash. What am I misunderstanding about `Password.new`

The User model

```
require 'bcrypt'

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # users.password_hash in the database is a :string
  include BCrypt

  def password
    @password ||= Password.new(password_hash)
  end

  def password=(new_password)
    @password = Password.create(new_password)
    self.password_hash = @password
  end
end
```

Creating an account

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  @user.password = params[:password]
  @user.save!
end
```

Authenticating a user

```
def login
  @user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
  if @user.password == params[:password]
    give_token
  else
    redirect_to home_url
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the line of code `if @user.password == params[:password]` is not comparing the encrypted hash with the unencrypted password `params[:password]`. It takes `params[:password]` and hashes it before doing a comparison. The hashing of `params[:password]` is obscured by `==` which turns out to be a method call.